# Fail with dummy_array<int, 6> arr();

Tags: c++, c++17

The problem is declaration of the array.

We can comment the

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list> 

template <typename Type, size_t const SIZE>
class dummy_array {
    Type data[SIZE] = {};

  public:
    dummy_array(){}
    ~dummy_array(){}

    Type& operator[](size_t const index)
    {
      if (index < SIZE)
        return data[index];
      throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
    }

    Type const& operator[](size_t const index) const
    {
      if (index < SIZE)
        return data[index];
      throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
    }

};
int main()
{
    {
      dummy_array<int, 6> arr();
      arr[0] = 1;
      arr[1] = 2;

      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " " ;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why declaration with  "dummy_array arr();" lead the failures as below.
Build log :

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:34:12: error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]

   arr[0] = 1;

        ^
```

main.cpp:34:16: error: assignment of read-only location '* arr'

```
   arr[0] = 1;

            ^
```

main.cpp:35:12: error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]

```
   arr[1] = 2;

        ^
```

main.cpp:35:16: error: assignment of read-only location '*(arr + 1)'

```
   arr[1] = 2;

            ^
```

main.cpp:38:27: error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]

```
     std::cout << arr[i] << " " ;

                       ^
```

Comment: Replace `dummy_array<int, 6> arr();` with `dummy_array<int, 6> arr{};` or just `dummy_array<int, 6> arr;`, you might have got a warning `empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration`

Comment: Thanks you so much. I got your answer, because compiler see that as function, and make fail with violate accessing to elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
dummy_array<int, 6> arr();
```

This can be seen as both a function declaration or a variable declaration.

The compiler always prefer a function declaration to a variable declaration, so you actually declared a function called arr, taking no argument and returning a dummy_array. Use this instead:

```cpp
dummy_array<int, 6> arr{};
```

Comment: Actually it's not the Most Vexing Parse; that's a misconception. (And the article you link to does explain that.) However, the rest of your answer is correct.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't explain it any more. Used to.

Comment: I don't have access to Effective STL right now, so I'm gonna trust you on this. Section 8.2 of the standard does talk about function style casts in declarations, but of course, doesn't mention the name "Most Vexing Parse". TIL

Comment: The vexing parse I'm dealing with in the moment is always the most vexing. ;)

Comment: It's a common misconception. It stems from the same language rules, ultimately, sort of. But this is not a "trick" or even really a surprise; it's just a mistake/typo. The MVP comes in when you write something that looks like it _should_ be an object declaration (which this does not!) but turns out not to be.

Comment: `dummy_array<int, 6> arr;` would have the same effect  (the class has a user-defined constructor so both syntaxes result in calling the constructor)

Comment: Thanks Khoyo, I got your keyword(Most vexing parse), i think it helps me understand bug later.